# Why don't SQL stored procedures parse image path strings?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am creating a cheat/fan page for [Doodle Creatures](http://joybits.org/games/doodle-creatures/#all). I have gotten the page to work, but I am using inline SQL instead of stored procedures. I have tried making my Select statements stored procedures, but the image info doesn't get parsed correctly.

Here is my SQL data source using the stored procedure:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQL_CreatureCombos" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:KJAI_DBConnectionString %>' 
     SelectCommand="SelectCreatureCombos"
     SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

[image: Creature Combos data source using a stored procedure.]

Here is my aspx page as it is now:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQL_CreatureCombos" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:KJAI_DBConnectionString %>' 
     SelectCommand="SELECT [Animal1].[AnimalImage] AS AnimalImage1, [Animal2].[AnimalImage] AS AnimalImage2, [Animal1].[AnimalImageAltText] AS AltText1, [Animal2].[AnimalImageAltText] AS AltText2, [Animal1].[AnimalImageToolTip] AS ToolTip1, [Animal2].[AnimalImageToolTip] AS ToolTip2, 
    [Genes].[GeneImg], [Genes].[GeneAltText], [Genes].[GeneToolTip] FROM [CreatureCombos]
INNER JOIN [Animals] AS Animal1 
       ON [CreatureCombos].[NewCreatureID] = Animal1.[AnimalId]
    INNER JOIN [Animals] AS Animal2 
       ON [CreatureCombos].[ComboAnimalID] = Animal2 .[AnimalId]
INNER JOIN [Genes] ON [CreatureCombos].[ComboGeneID] = [Genes].[GeneId]
    ORDER BY AltText2;">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:DataList ID="DL_CreatureCombos" runat="server" 
     EnableViewState="false" DataSourceID="SQL_CreatureCombos" 
     RepeatColumns="6" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="IMG_ComboAnimal" runat="server" 
             ImageUrl='<%# Bind("AnimalImage2")%>' 
             AlternateText='<%# Bind("AltText2")%>' 
             ToolTip='<%# Bind("ToolTip2")%>' Width="25%" />+
        <asp:Image ID="IMG_ComboGene" runat="server" 
             ImageUrl='<%# Bind("GeneImg")%>' 
             AlternateText='<%# Bind("GeneAltText")%>' 
             ToolTip='<%# Bind("GeneToolTip")%>' Width="25%" />=
        <asp:Image ID="IMG_NewAnimal" runat="server" 
             ImageUrl='<%# Bind("AnimalImage1")%>' 
             AlternateText='<%# Bind("AltText1")%>' 
             ToolTip='<%# Bind("ToolTip1")%>' Width="25%" />
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Here are my Animals and CreatureCombos tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Animals] 
(
    [AnimalId]           INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Animal]             VARCHAR (30)  NOT NULL,
    [GroupID]            INT           NOT NULL,
    [AnimalImage]        VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [AnimalImageAltText] VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [AnimalImageToolTip] VARCHAR (50)  NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AnimalId] ASC),
    FOREIGN KEY ([GroupID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Groups] ([GroupId])
);
```

I used `VARCHAR(MAX)` because I read somewhere that Microsoft would be getting rid of the `Image` data type in the near future. I wanted to make sure my data would not be changed when the new SQL Server version was released..

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CreatureCombos] 
(
    [CreatureId]    INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [NewCreatureID] INT NOT NULL,
    [ComboAnimalID] INT NOT NULL,
    [ComboGeneID]   INT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CreatureId] ASC),
    FOREIGN KEY ([ComboGeneID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Genes] ([GeneId]),
    FOREIGN KEY ([ComboAnimalID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Animals] ([AnimalId]),
    FOREIGN KEY ([NewCreatureID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Animals] ([AnimalId])
);
```

Any help would be much appreciated! I can't believe it won't work anymore!! :-(

EDIT: I fixed the problem with the inner SQL; I shouldn't have refreshed my datalist. It replaced my image controls with labels.

[image: My page, working with inline SQL.]

Comment: Do you store image data in **AnimalImage** and display back that data to browser? Could you also post the **ASPX page**?

Comment: What exactly is stored in `AnimalImage`?  The path to an image on your web server?  And yes, we really need to see how you are binding the data source to page controls.

Comment: `AnimalImage` stores location of the image. For example, the image for my `Rhino` record would be `~/Images/Doodle Creatures/Animals/Big Animals/Rhino.png`

Comment: " image info doesn't get parsed correctly". This tells us nothing. What is the image info exactly, how is it not parsed correctly?

Comment: Yes, `Image` is deprecated - but it should be "replaced" with `VARBINARY(MAX)` (a **binary** datatype) - not `VARCHAR(MAX)` (a **string** datatype)

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong; I put all of my inline SQL into stored procedures and it the page works perfectly! I think my datalist refreshed itself and created labels where there should be images when I first encapsulated my SQL code and called its stored procedure. My bad. :-)